# What's the AS3 equivalent for MovieClip.CreateEmptyMovieClip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, haxe

I have some older AS2-style Haxe code which uses `flash.Lib.Current.CreateEmptyMovieClip()` to create a slideshow of disk-based images. It creates a new clip for holding each image and simply fades each image in and out with alpha levels.

Compiling it with `-swf -swf-version 8` creates an SWF file fine and this works in the browser.

However, I'm in the process to converting this over to `-swf9` and I find that the `MovieClip` no longer has that method.

How do you load up a series of images with Haxe (AS3-style)?

The code, for what it's worth, is along these lines:

```
static function main() {
  mc = flash.Lib.current;
  var clip : MovieClip;

  clip = mc.createEmptyMovieClip ("clip_000", mc.getNextHighestDepth());
  clip.loadMovie ("demo_img000.jpg");

  : : :
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just create a new display object w/o linking it to a clip in the library like this:

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite() // -- creates a sprite
var clip:MovieClip = new MovieClip() // -- creates a movie clip
```

You can then add it to another display object by using the `addChild()` method:

```
myOtherClip.addChild( sprite )
```

The above line will add the new clip to the top of the display list, just like using `getNextHighestDepth()`.

If you want to add a clip a depth between two other clips you can use:

```
myOtherClip.addChildAt( movieClip, 2 ); // -- adds a clip at 2 levels up from 0
```

As for loading an image, loadMovie does not exist in AS3. You need to use the Loader and URLRequest objects like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( 'path_to_my_image.jpg' );
loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete );
loader.load( request );

function onLoadComplete( event:Event ):void
{
     if( loader.content ){
         clip.addChild( loader.content )
     }
}
```

Comment: This is one of the things that's *much* nicer in AS3.

Comment: I'll no doubt accept this answer since it appears to work okay (at least preliminarily). One thing I'm not getting - how to you specify where the sprite/clip goes on the main clip? In other words, `x=mc.createTextField(name,mc.getHighestDepth(),0,300,400,20)` specifies where the field goes and its size. How do you do this with just `x = new TextField()`?

Comment: clip.x = 300;
clip.y = 400;
parentClip.addChild( clip )